# Keyboard Interrupt interactive Python in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: python, visual-studio

If I execute a command in the interactive mode in python in Visual Studio with the Python Tools for Visual Studio IDE, I would like to be able to interrupt that command with a set of keystrokes e.g CTRL + C as in MATLAB.

The [PTVS docs on interactive mode](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Interactive-REPL) don't mention anything in particular. Google searches turned up empty.

Comment: For the python shell usually this exact keystroke combo CTRL+C will abort the execution by throwing a KeyboardInterrupt Exception. I'm not sure about VS though.

Comment: @Philipp, yeah I was hoping that would work in VS as well. Unfortunately that is not the case.

Comment: The 'reset' icon at the top left of the interactive pane is the only thing I found that did something similar (VS2017 Enterprise 15.3.3). Seems to remove all variables from your session as well (as the name would suggest).

Answer (score 1):

The stop button, which is red square outline, does this job. Your running code will respond as if it had a keyboard interrupt.

[image]

Note: This is an old question, but I ended up here by googling and found no useful answer, so I posted this one once I found it.

Answer (score 0):

To abort the execution of a python script in the Interactive Window of Visual Studio, you have to use the **Reset** button. This is the designed way to reset your environment and cleaning up the associated environment memory.

Comment: The question was about aborting the execution of a single line of python code in the interactive window. PTVS unfortunately has no way of doing this as the project managers have very strange development priorities.